# How to change color of certain row inside ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, fragment, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment which I fill with data like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mNames);
```

For certain name inside mNames I want text to have different color. How can I accomplish that?

I tried this to get a count of child views but it returns 0:

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = getListView();
    int count = listView.getChildCount();
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.w("COUNT", "" + count);
}
```

I also tried variations with overriding `getView()` in ArrayAdapter but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own adapter class like this:

```
public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<String> items;


    public MyGridAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
        this.items = items;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }

        if (items.get(position).equals("James")){
            // Do what you want with it
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change raw text color with **ArrayAdapter**

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
//flag is a boolean for selected raws
if(flag== True){
  text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}   
return view;
}
};
```

Change the raw color with **SimpleAdapter**

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
//change color is a method to pass selected raws for change color
if (changecolor(position)) ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.main_name)).setTextColor(0xffff0000);
return view;
}

}
```